# Unable to find module with Gradle path. Linking to library -unspecified instead

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

**Update 2** This has been fixed in Android Studio 1.2 Beta 3

**Update:** This has reportedly been fixed in an upcoming release of Android Studio.

In Android Studio 1.2 Beta 2 I started getting the following warnings when syncing Gradle.

```
Failed to set up dependencies
Warning:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':Library1'. Linking to library 'Library1-unspecified' instead.
Warning:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':Library2'. Linking to library 'Library2-unspecified' instead.
```

I've noticed that jumping to a declaration declared in one of the library modules pulls up the Decompiler instead of just going to the actual source in the library module.

In my Android Studio Project I have the following modules:

```
- App
- Library1
- Library2
```

Module: App `build.gradle` snippet:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':Library1')
    compile project(':Library2')
}
```

`settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':App'
include ':Library1'
include ':Library2'
project(':Library1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../library1/lib')
project(':Library2').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Library2/lib')
```

Comment: I just ignored them. Cmd + F9 rebuilds the project with no problems.

Comment: This specific issue is being addressed in an update to Android Studio. I'll post an answer once it is released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known bug introduced in 1.2 Beta 2.

See [This issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65915) on the Android issue tracker. Fix should be out within hours.

Comment: Thanks. Yes Android Studio 1.2 Beta 3 fixes this issue.

Comment: The issue is resolved here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163888

Comment: I have Android Studio 1.4 RC 3 but issue is still there

Comment: This seems to have re-surfaced in Android Studio 3.0. Been unable to have this working since Canary 3. Tested again on Beta 2

Answer (score 54):

I faced this with Android Studio 2.2.3. The problem was with the `.iml` file that was causing the problem.

After importing the module folder into the project directory and adding the changes to include module in `settings.gradle`, delete the `.iml` file from the module folder and do a Gradle Sync. Then right click on any module in the Project Window and click on "Configure Project Subset...", if the imported module is not checked, check it and Android Studio should do a Gradle Sync. By then the imported module will appear in the Project Window and will have a `.iml` file regenerated that is does not cause any issues.

Comment: Close `Android Studio`. And I deleted all the `*.iml` and the `.idea` folder in my FileExplorer/FileSystem. Sync the project, then solved. My Android Studio is v2.3.1.

Comment: @ahasbini no, i just do as kimu said

Comment: Still a problem on 3.0 and 3.1 :(

Comment: Could you provide with more details? Did you try the above suggested solutions? Probably should  open a new question...

Comment: Thank you! I was banging my head against the wall for HOURS and Gradle wouldn't stop complaining that it couldn't find the module even though the module was clearly there. This saved my butt. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

1. delete the `.iml` file under the `error` module.
2. restart Android studio

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer - plain and simple.

Comment: Thanks, This helped me to resolve the issue but gradle took long time to sync when we delete .iml files. Wish u patience.

Answer (score 9):

Right click project, Select "Configure Project Subset ..." and select your module, rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works on AS 2.1.1 after some unspecified problem with import library module

Comment: dunno about right click. but cmd+shift+A will help you find this menu option

Answer (score 5):

I met the same problem on AS 2.0 preview,
and I fixed it by following steps:

1.Rename the module.
2.Change the names in app/build.gradle and setting.gradle.
3.Start gradle sync.

I don't know why but it works on my issue.

Comment: sounds like a cache issue but i invalidated cache and restarted and didn't fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Check in settings. of your app. 
Down there is the field "Load/Unload Modules"

Your module might be unloaded, that's why Android Studio ignores it even if you specify it in Gradle.

At least that was the problem for me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `React-native>60`, then you should run `npx jetify` on root of your project before doing Gradle sync.

Comment: This was very useful. Handled my issue.

Answer (score 3):

For me the following worked in Android Studio 3.5.3

First of all, **check if the path is correct** in your Gradle settings.

If the path is correct then **invalidate caches & restart** by navigating to the top 'File' menu

Comment: I just did a re-sync. Little faster than invalidating caches and restarting ... lots o re-indexing. In my case it happens every time I open Android Studio. I think it is because I have a module that is shared with an Intellij Java gradle project. Have not figured out what one does to the other.  The error is one way. Once it works in Android Studio opening the Intellij project has no problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and solved it by clicking on

> **File> Ivalidate cache / Restart...**

as shown below:

[image: print android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

This problem can also occur when you change the path to the module.

*settings.gradle*

```
include ':app', ':filechooserlibrary'
project(':filechooserlibrary').projectDir = new File('../../repos-github/file-chooser/file-chooser-library/filechooserlibrary')
```

I changed the path to `'../../github/file-chooser/file-chooser-library/filechooserlibrary'`

The old path did not exist any more. But then, instead of accepting the new path, Android Studio recreated the old path structure thus referring to an empty directory.

**Solution:**
So, I deleted this obsolete path structure and restarted Android Studio, after deleting the .iml file (I don't know if this is necessary, but it cannot do harm). Then I reimported the Gradle project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an updated version of `NDK`.

I faced the same issue.
I was using `NDK` version `r17c`. Issue solve after using `r21e`.

- Android Studio Version: `4.1.3`
- OS: Ubuntu `18.04.5`